# Using regex to match HTML

Tags: java, regex

Here's an input HTML string:

<p>**Johnny:** My favorite color is pink<br />
**Sarah:** My favorite color is blue<br />
**Johnny:** Let's swap genders?<br />
**Sarah:** OK!<br />
</p>

I want to regex-match the **bolded** part above. Basically put, find any matches between ">" (or beginning of line) and ":"

I made this regex **`(?>)[^>](.+):`** but it didn't work correctly, it bolded the parts below, including the <p> tag. I don't want to match any HTML tag:

**<p>Johnny:** My favorite color is pink<br />
**Sarah:** My favorite color is blue<br />
**Johnny:** Let's swap genders?<br />
**Sarah:** OK!<br />
</p>

I am using Java, with code like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("`(?>)[^>](.+):`", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(string);
```

Comment: In which language are you writing the regex ? You would be better off using a HTMLParser library/module available in the language of your choice than using handcrafted regexes to parse HTML.

Comment: Java. Your suggestion is good, I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Obligitory HTML/Regex warning:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: And they still keep coming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
String str = "<p>Johnny Smith: My favorite color abc: is pink<br />" +
"Sarah: My favorite color is dark: blue<br />" +
"Johnny: Let's swap: genders?<br />" +
"Sarah: OK: sure!<br />" +
"</p>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:>|^)([\\w\\s]+)(?=:)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str); 
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Johnny Smith
Sarah
Johnny
Sarah
```

Comment: That almost worked. If we use the name 'Johnny Smith' instead of 'Johnny', then it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a match when a word is followed by ':' then "\w+:" should be enough. But if you want to include the '>' possibility you can try:

```
        String s = "<p>Johnny: My favorite color is pink<br />" +
            "Sarah: My favorite color is blue<br />" +
            "Johnny: Let's swap genders?<br />" +
            "Sarah: OK!<br />" +
            "</p>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[>]?(\\w+):");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.start()+" : "+m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I saw a potential problem: If the name is "Johnny Smith", then only "Smith" is matched and not "Johnny Smith". Almost there! Thanks!